# avoid refreshing of page when url was change

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

how can i avoid refreshing of page when my url was change upon clicking of button? using javascript? ajax or jquery? thanks

here is my code

```
function myFunctionD(id) { var x=document.getElementById(id);   
var myURL = "http:www.balita_permonth.php";
document.location = myURL + "?t_id=" + x.id ;
}

<a href="docview.php?id=30" id="30" onclick="myFunctionD(30)" class="30" target="iframe_a">August 7, 2013</a></li>
<a href="docview.php?id=31" id="31" onclick="myFunctionD(31)" class="31" target="iframe_a">August 8, 2013</a></li>
```

Comment: Ajax, with or without jQuery.

Comment: your code has no sense. the links try to load docview.php into a probably already existing iframe but at the same time you call a function that tells the browser to change location.i don't understand what you wanna achieve.

Comment: use event.preventDefault() inside your callback function.